# Prestashop 1.6 / How to get carrier id, to use it in order-carrier.tpl

Tags: css, smarty, prestashop, var

I'm using Prestashop 1.6

In **order-carrier.tpl**, I'm trying to get the **carrier id**, because I would like to use it in the css class of the `<div>`.

For exemple : `div.delivery_option.carrier_id_33`

I tried this :

```
{$cart->id_carrier}
```

But it doesn't really work.

Comment: try `$carrier.instance->id` where the variable `$carrier` is available

Answer (score 1):

If it's in TPL file, you need to use **getcontext()** first

So in this case it would be

```
{context::getContext()->cart->id_carrier}
```

Answer (score 1):

Late answer here, but I write mainly for future reference.

First, there should always be a global $carrier smarty variable available to templates. Just check placing a `{debug}` tag on the place you want to use it and see if it's there.

Second, DO NOT use `id_carrier`. It's quite strange but you will loose it. It's not a really reliable property. I discussed the issue with the developers some time ago. You should use id_reference instead: that won't change.

http://forge.prestashop.com/browse/PSCSX-4651

So, to sum up:

```
{assign var=carrier_instance value=$carrier.instance}

{* then later somewhere: *}

{$carrier_instance->id_reference}
```

this will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<div class="delivery_option {if ($option@index % 2)}alternate_{/if}item {foreach $option.carrier_list as $carrier}carrier_id_{$carrier.instance->id}{/foreach}">
```

The carriers are not directly accessible, but they are encapsuled inside the variable `$option`

Answer (score 0):

Since I always get here whenever I search for id_reference from smarty I'll post my solution for 1.7

```
{$carrier_id = context::getContext()->cart->id_carrier.id_reference}
```

Returns the carrier_id_reference, the nice one cause carrier_id changes everytime you modify a carrier, so the real ID you need in order to operate with carriers is id_reference